# In C# .NET standard why is the thread state "Running" determined using the bit test `(ThreadState & (Stopped | Unstarted)) == 0`

Tags: c#, multithreading

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-thread-states), :

> Because the Running state has a value of 0, it is not possible to
>   perform a bit test to discover this state. Instead, the following test
>   (in pseudo-code) can be used:
>
> ```
> if ((state & (Unstarted | Stopped)) == 0)   // implies Running
> ```
>
> Threads are often in more than one state at any given time.

and [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_ThreadState_Running)

> The Thread.ThreadState property of a thread provides the current state
>   of a thread. Applications must use a bitmask to determine whether a
>   thread is running. Since the value for `Running` is zero (0), test
>   whether a thread is running by using C# code such as
>   `(myThread.ThreadState & (ThreadState.Stopped | ThreadState.Unstarted))
>   == 0` or Visual Basic code such as `(myThread.ThreadState And (ThreadState.Stopped Or ThreadState.Unstarted)) = 0`.

Searching through SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063612/check-whether-the-thread-is-running-or-not-in-c-sharp),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232521/thread-isalive-and-thread-threadstate-threadstate-running),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010030/what-value-is-the-threadstate-property)) I only find why ThreadState should not be used for flow control since the state checked could immediately change. For cases when you check it for debugging why would you use the bitmask above as opposed to just `myThread.ThreadState==0`?

Comment: Because of AbortRequested or SuspendRequested or ...?

Comment: @SirRufo I don't follow. Then it wouldn't be in Running state but why is 0 bitwise &'ed with the initial or final states?

Comment: A **running** thread can also have the state **AbortRequested** (should abort ASAP) or maybe **Background**. Now ThreadState is != 0 although it is running

Comment: Since `ThreadState` is marked with the `[FlagsAttribute]`, can you even do `myThread.ThreadState == 0`?

Comment: @SirRufo Nobody give up on me. Still confused. The RunningState is the only one that is mutually exclusive of any other state because of its zero value, not because of possible status of the thread. But it's also not in the running state when it's in abortRequested or anything else. Now why would you & 0 with the initial and final values?

Comment: @SirRufo The given line though is not to include the states that are running but not zero.

Comment: To answer the main question: Because the thread is running when it is NOT Unstarted and NOT Stopped. It is a definition from the class designer

Comment: @SirRufo ok, I understand now. It *is* checking for isAlive() after all.

Comment: @SirRufo +1 on a random question of yours. System wouldn't let me do 2. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enum / bit mask here is to restrict you to checking two bits. There are *other bits* in the status that do not tell you whether it is running or not - so them being set (1) or not set (0) *doesn't change* whether you should consider it running. For example, having the `WaitSleepJoin` bit set, or the `SuspendRequested` bit set - doesn't change that it is "running", for most useful purposes.

So: the `state & (Unstarted | Stopped)` says "just looking at these two bits, and ignoring the rest"...

The full set of *documented* flags are:

```
[Serializable, Flags, ComVisible(true)]
public enum ThreadState
{
    Aborted = 256,
    AbortRequested = 128,
    Background = 4,
    Running = 0,
    Stopped = 16,
    StopRequested = 1,
    Suspended = 64,
    SuspendRequested = 2,
    Unstarted = 8,
    WaitSleepJoin = 32
}
```

I say "documented", because enums aren't enforced - the value could theoretically come back as 2050 or -6 - with whatever bit flags are set for those.

Comment: and it's confusing because nonzero is false so (unstarted | stopped) means NOT unstarted or stopped

Comment: @user5389726598465 maybe, but in other ways : checking for `0` is nice - most of the flags are a *deviation from the normal state* - 0 being "all normal". Arguably the background flag being set doesn't change "normal"